# How can I style a react bootstrap NavDropdown title atrribute and the NavDropdown.Item Links inside?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
      <NavDropdown title="Products">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Meat Alternatives</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Soy Products</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Vegan Deserts</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Production</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
```

I am new to react-bootstrap and I want to style the nav dropdown menu with my own CSS. I have tried using CSS selectors by wrapping the whole thing with a div, giving it a class of .style-dropdown, and targeting the title atribute

```
  <div className='style-dropdown'>
          <NavDropdown title="Products">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Meat Alternatives</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Soy Products</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Vegan Deserts</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Production</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          </div>
```

My CSS:
`.style-dropdown[title] { color: palevioletred !important; }`

I have tried searching google but could'nt find the answer. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to declare the style directly within the `render()` method of your component, and then apply that to your `<NavDropdown>`.

```js
render() {
    let styleDropdown = {
        color: palevioletred
    };
    return (
        <NavDropdown title="Products" style={styleDropdown}>
           ...
        </NavDropdown>
    )
}
```

If you're using CSS modules (and I'd definitely recommend you do), you can import your styles and directly apply the className to the element.

```js
import styles from "./nav.module.css";
```

```html
<NavDropdown className={styles.myTitleStyle}>
    ...
</NavDropdown>
```

EDIT: The NavDropdown title renders as an `<a>` element, so in your CSS, you'll want:

```css
.myTitleStyle a
{
    color: palevioletred !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked for the inside of the dropdown. but the title is still not being styled

Comment: Did you inspect the rendered HTML element to see if you're applying the style to the correct HTML element?

Comment: @MegaMindTheCoder Updated with the CSS selector to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't see your last solution now it works. everything you have suggested has been helpful